How do I add new releases to apt-mirror's mirroring config?
My apt mirror server os version is 22(jammy). I would like to add version 24(noble, oracular) mirroring to my apt mirror server, so the mirror.list file was modified.
Contents of /etc/apt/mirror.list:
deb-amd64 https://mirror.kakao.com/ubuntu noble main

deb-i386 https://mirror.kakao.com/ubuntu noble-update main

deb-amd64 https://mirror.kakao.com/ubuntu oracular main

deb-i386 https://mirror.kakao.com/ubuntu oracular-update main

I modified the mirror.list file as above and ran the apt-mirror command, but the noble and oracular mirror files were not downloaded.
Can't I download a higher version(v24:noble, v24:oracular) of apt mirror on my current Ubuntu OS version(v22:jammy)?
